# What should the return type be for Redux selectors?

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

In my definition of a Redux store I have

```js
import { Device } from "react-native-ble-plx"
import { configureStore, createSlice  } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'


const bleSlice = createSlice( {
    name: 'ble',
    initialState: {scannedDevices: [], isScanning: false} as StoreBLEState,
    reducers: {
        deviceAdd(state, action) {
            state.scannedDevices.push(action.payload)
        },
        scanIsRunning(state, action) {
            state.isScanning = action.payload
        },
        devicesClear(state) {
            state.scannedDevices = []
        },
    }
} )

export const storeBLE = { ...bleSlice.actions }

export const store = configureStore( {
    reducer: {
        ble: bleSlice.reducer,
    }
} )

export interface StoreBLEDeviceInfo {
  name: string | null;
  id: string;
}

export interface StoreBLEState {
  scannedDevices: StoreBLEDeviceInfo[];
  isScanning: boolean;
}

export type StoreRootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
```

which I use in a component with something like

```js
const bleState: StoreBLEState = useSelector((state: StoreRootState) => state.ble)
```

and elsewhere with, for example

```js
store.dispatch(storeBLE.devicesClear())
```

These last two uses, as well as each of the function definitions under `reducers` get flagged by my type checking (the latter with "Void function return value is used" and the first two for missing a return type specification).

- What is the return type of `(state: StoreRootState) => state.ble`?
- What is the return type of each of the functions specified under `reducers` in the first code fragment (e.g of `{deviceAdd(state, action) { ... }`)?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a flagging by a type checker, but probably by a linter rule. Honestly, I'd disable that linter rule - it doesn't add any value.

For the question though:

```
        deviceAdd(state, action): void {
            state.scannedDevices.push(action.payload)
        },
```

and

```
(state: StoreRootState): StoreBLEState => state.ble
```

(you would have gotten that one just by hovering over it)

Comment: I didn't get either of those by hovering, FWIW.

Comment: hover over the `ble` of `state.ble` - assuming you use vscode

Comment: WebStorm. There was no info from hovering, which is why I was perplexed.

Comment: I can really recommend trying VSCode for a bit. WebStorm tries to "guess" types with a custom algorithm instead of using the official TS language server, which results in all kinds of wrong type guesses - especially with Redux Toolkit. They have open tickets about this that they are ignoring for years now.

Comment: That explains a lot. I've been confused about the number of glitches and announces I encounter with WebStorm, and often find that things that seem essential have tickets that have been open for ages. I'm reluctant to switch IDEs at this point though (lots invested in JetBrains customization).

Comment: What about `store.dispatch(storeBLE.devicesClear())`? All uses of `dispatch` get flagged with "Void function return value is used". Is that just an IDE error?

Comment: Probably. WebStorm probably thinks that `slice.actions.devicesClear` has the same function signature as the `devicesClear` case reducer function - which returns nothing. WebStorm often just guesses "by name" in those cases.

Comment: Actually this is wrong. What's missing is that each of the reducers should `            return state` (`Draft<StoreBLEState>`, not `void`). The warning is correct.

Comment: No, Redux Toolkit reducers explicitly do not need to return state. They can if you want to write hand-written immutable updates, but they don't need to if you write mutating logic. `void` is perfectly fine.
Also, that would probably just make WebStorm think that the action creators return `store`, not an action like they really do.

Comment: Well it made WebStorm happy.